# Issue with addRule - not validate numeric values HTML_QuickForm

Tags: php, html, pear

I need to add validation for HTML_QuickForm. I tried but still cannot see any error message. This is the code I'm using.

```
$element = HTML_QuickForm::createElement('text','text1','Length');
$element->SetValue($app->GetLength());
$form->addRule('text1', 'Length should be a numeric value', 'numeric');
$form->addElement($element);
```

Once the form submitted,

```
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
    if($form->validate()){
        echo "form validated";
    }else{
        echo "validation fail";
    }
}
```

I always get "form validated" although `text1` has text values.

**UPDATE:**

I could display an alert message changing the code to this:

```
$form->addRule('text1', 'Length should be a numeric value', 'numeric', null, 'client');
```

But I need to display an error message instead of alert. Also want to highlight the error field. In [documentation](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform.tutorial.php) says that QuickForm will automatically mark required fields in the form.

Any help on this would appreciate.

Comment: what us the reason for `=&`?

Comment: @chiliNUT I removed it since it is Deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the field to be required. Otherwise empty values are not validated.